# How to render HTML Django page to PDF?

Tags: html, django, pdf

I have a task to render an HTML page with dynamic data and turn it into PDF, but, I have a problem achieving it.

```
def makepdf(request):
    if request.POST:
        chatvs = Competirors.objects.get(id = int(request.POST.get('competitor', '')))
        jivo_staff = Manager.objects.get(id = int(request.POST.get('manager', '')))

        business = Field.objects.get(id = int(request.POST.get('filed', '')))

        business = business.link.all().order_by('?')[0:3]        

        context = {
            "chatvs" : chatvs,
            "jivo_staff" : jivo_staff,
            "business" : business,
        }

        tmpl = get_template('marketing/jivopdf.html', )
        html = tmpl.render(context)

        # and i have a problem there with pdfkit
```

I was using Pdfcrowd API, but it cuts all CSS styles and does not look nice. As for vvwkhtmltopdf/pdfkit - I don't know how to make it a rendered HTML page, as it accesses only the url/file/string.

Is there a way to render ready HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing the error you get.

But what I can see from your code, if this is your real code. Looks like a spelling mistake in `Competirors.objects.get`, should probably be named Competitors.

And if you get the POST data from a form, you shouldn't use it directly.
Never trust user input...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org/) .